# Should favicon be placed in the offline cache manifest

Tags: html, favicon, html5-appcache

Everything is in the title: should the favicon be placed in the CACHE section of a cache manifest?

What about a website that provides several favicon with different resolutions? Currently, the following can be used by some devices:

- 16x16: standard favicon
- 32: hidpi favicon
- 48: Windows desktop sortcuts
- 57: non-retina iPhones, iPod and Android
- 72: 1st & 2nd gen iPads
- 114: retina iPhones with iOS <= 6, Firefox for Android newtab tiles
- 120: retina iPhones with iOS >= 7
- 144: retina iPad with iOS <= 6, Win 8 tiles
- 152: retina iPad with iOS >= 7
- And maybe others...

While I'm ok with caching the favicons (16 & 32), I certainly don't want to cache all the other icons since most of them won't be used by the target device. Should they be place in the ONLINE section? Or in the FALLBACK section, pointing to the biggest icon (sounds like a bad idea, since size hints can be provided: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="57x57" href="icon-57.png">`)?

Comment: Hi @Cyrille, did you ever figure this out? I'm wondering the same thing. Right now I'm assuming that the browser will probably already cache the favicon, so I don't think it would be necessary.